# Can a file be transferred from an iPhone to Mac OS X using Bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, mac, bluetooth

Can a file be transferred from an iPhone to another iPhone/iPod/iPad and to my Mac/PC using Bluetooth?

Comment: Nice editing Jeff ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) for that, which I highly recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Not without using 3rd party software/apps.

Why not just plug it into USB? On windows this will appear as a mounted drive and on MAC you can use iPhoto or Image Capture (standard Apple apps) to get your pics off your iDevices.

Comment: Also, this should be on superuser...